# Sort array by index value (true , false)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hi I want my array to be sorted on basis of 'isStarted'  ture first,

Code snippet

```
  [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 127
        [name] => 23-3
        [isStarted] => false
        [isAdmin] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 125
        [name] => GameStartTesting
        [isStarted] => true
        [isAdmin] => 1
    )
```

I want isStarted first.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 usort ($array, function ($left, $right) {
        return $left['isStarted'] - $right['isStarted'];
    });
```